# how to make space on both side of the row uicollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have add a uicollectionView to the super view and decide the cell size like this:

```
- (nonnull __kindof UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(nonnull UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(!cell){
        cell = [[UICollectionViewCell alloc]init];
    }
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:cell.bounds];

    int r = arc4random_uniform(4);
    NSString *imageName = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", r] stringByAppendingString:@".jpg"];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    [cell addSubview:imageView];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    return cell;
}



- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(180, 340);
}
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(nonnull UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1500;
}
```

And it looks like this on the device:

[image]

I want the space between two images and the padding and tailing of each row to be equal.

I also want to set the space between each row.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> func UIEdgeInsetsMake(_ top: CGFloat, _ left: CGFloat, _ bottom:
> CGFloat, _ right: CGFloat) -> UIEdgeInsets
>
> **Description**
>
> Creates an edge inset for a button or view.
>
> An inset is a margin around a
> rectangle. Positive values represent margins closer to the center of
> the rectangle, while negative values represent margins further from
> the center.

**sectionInset** will give space on Leading and Trailing of collectionview scetion

```
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 4.0, 0, 4.0)

    self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: coll_frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    self.collectionView.delegate = self
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self
    self.collectionView.register(PreferenceCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: String(describing: PreferenceCollectionViewCell.self))
    self.addSubview(self.collectionView)
```

These two methods will give space to each cell, first you can pass 0.0 and try, how it works.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 6
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 6
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the storyboard, select `UICollectionView`, goto property and change  Inset.

[image]

> Edit
>   Do it by code

Add UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

```
class SecondVC: UIViewController , UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
```

Implement this below func

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets{
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    }
```

Output

[image]

**In Obj-c**

Use this func

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
                        layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout 
        insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section;
```

and return `UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);`

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I am not using storyboard

Comment: @armnotstrong check Edit.

Answer (score 0):

try this

pass the CGSizeMake what ever you want

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

return CGSizeMake((self.view.frame.size.width/5) , (self.view.frame.size.width/5) - 25);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Provide inter cell spacing and inter line spacing for cell. It adjusts the cell based on the value provided.

Hope this helps.